# CKEditor Custom Toolbar button to add onClick Link

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

I am trying to add a button inside the CKEditor thats exactly like the link functionality but it will add onclick instead of href, for example, if I want to add new link for google, it will generate html code like this

`<h1><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_system');">Go to google</a></h1>`

Thanks.

Comment: Am i understanding you right, you want to add a button to the toolbar with a custom functionality?

Comment: thats true, I couldnt know how to make the functionality as I said